# Show that the discrete random variable converges to zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Given a discrete random variable $X=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$
with $p = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2n} & 1-\frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{2n}
\end{pmatrix}$

How would I show that $X$ converges to zero in probability?

I have looked this up on Wikipedia and if I understood correctly, this can be done using Chebyshev's inequality: $P[|X-E[X]| \geq \epsilon] \leq \frac{Var[X]}{\epsilon^2}$

So I would need to know the expected value and variance to use this formula. 
$$E(X) = -\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n} = 0$$

$$Var(X) = ((-1-0)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2n}) + ((0-0)^2 \cdot (1-\frac{1}{n})) + ((1-0)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2n}) = \frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{n}$$

Now using Chebyshev:

$$P[|X| \geq \epsilon] \leq \frac{1}{n \epsilon^2}$$

Now I'm not sure how to continue. Let $n \rightarrow \infty$ then denominator will greater and greater than the nominator and thus go towards zero. Is it correct like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. And the other way is to find probabilities $\mathbb P(|X|\geq \epsilon)$ directly. If $0<\epsilon\leq 1$ then
$$
\mathbb P(|X|\geq \epsilon) = \mathbb P(|X|=1)=\mathbb P(X=-1)+\mathbb P(X=1)=\frac1n+\frac1n=\frac2n\to 0
$$
as $n\to\infty$. For $\epsilon>1$ 
$$
\mathbb P(|X|\geq \epsilon) = 0.
$$
We prove that for each $\epsilon>0$, $\mathbb P(|X|\geq \epsilon)\to 0$  as $n\to\infty$. By definition, it means that $X\xrightarrow{p}0$ as $n\to\infty$.